# How to find a specific string within a group of records, for all groups of records

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Not sure how to solve this problem, which seems like it should be easy.

I need to identify all of the students who are not enrolled in a certain class that is required for graduation.

Using the example below, if `ClassNumber` C30 is required for graduation, I want the query to return the `studentIDs` 1 and 2 - neither of whom are registered in `ClassNumber` C30.

Am I missing something simple?  I'm not sure how to get SQL to evaluate whether a string is present or not in `ClassNumber` within a set of records grouped by `studentID`.

```
ClassEnrollment Table
=====================
ID|ClassNumber|StudentID  
1 |A10        |1  
2 |A10        |1    
3 |B20        |1  
4 |A10        |2  
5 |B20        |2  
6 |B20        |2  
7 |C30        |3  
8 |A10        |3  
9 |A10        |3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this one table, you can do it as an aggregation query:

```
select StudentId
from ClassEnrollment
group by StudentId
having sum(case when ClassNumber = 'C30' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If you have another table of students, I think a more natural way is to use `not exists`:

```
select StudentId
from Students s
where not exists (select 1
                  from ClassEnrollment ce
                  where ClassNumber = 'C30' and ce.StudentId = s.StudentId
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not terribly efficient, but one way:

```
select distinct StudentID from ClassEnrollment
minus
select StudentID  from ClassEnrollment
  where ClassNumber = 'C30';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this:

```
select distinct ce.StudentID from ClassEnrollment ce
where not exists (select 1 from ClassEnrollment ce2 where ce2.StudentID = ce.StudentID and ce2.ClassNumber = 'C30')
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard, and best performing, approach is to use an outer join with the non-key condition in the *join* condition, filtering out successful joins:

```
select s.*
from Student s
left join ClassEnrollment e
    on e.StudentID = s.Id
    and e.ClassNumber = 'C30'
where e.StudentID is null
```

This works because missed joins have all nulls in the row, and while the join condition is applied *during* the join, the where clause is applied *after* the join, so specifying that a joined column (that can't actually be null) is null leaves only missed joins.